# RSpec stubbing a complex Rails result to test one nested field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, activerecord, rspec

I'm using RSpec's stubbing functionality to stub a `where()` call on an object:

`allow(ActiveRecordObject).to_receive(:where).and_return(result)`

This works great when the expected result is simple, such as an instance of the ActiveRecordObject with a field set to a certain value.

However, the result I want to test is more complex. I'm intending to test a value set on another ActiveRecordObject that is nested three deep through Rails `hasMany` functionality and this is more tricky. For example, I'd like ...

`expect(result[:child_object][:test_target][:field]).to eq(value)`

... to work as a test after the function that I'm testing is called.

The way I've attempted and so far failed to achieve this is by copying the structure of the object so the result is a considerably more complex.

What I'd like to do is stub the actual call (or value, if a call isn't really made) to test_target so when the call is made a much more simple stub is hit. This seems to me to be better as it creates less brittle, easier to understand code.

I've also tried stubbing a `where()` method on the class TestTarget.

What is the correct way to configure values in linked ActiveRecord objects in RSpec so that when the parent object is called the resulting structure contains a value hard-coded for test.

Also, is this possible without using Factory Girl (tech leads at work have decided that we want to move away from using FactoryGirl)

Comment: Is it not an option to remove all stubbing and just have your test setup create the desired state in the Database using fixtures or Factory Girl?

Comment: @tpbowden - updated in response, see last sentence